# The apply method in handler is being called multiple times for invalid transactions(sawtooth)

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

While performing transactions on sawtooth node from client(using go sdk) the apply method in handler is being called multiple times.[response after submitting invalid transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niOiC.png)

Comment: Adding a comment here, because the solution for one of the known behavior is in progress. The logic here is that there is only one pending transaction and that is evaluated to invalid transaction. If you had submitted another valid transaction you wouldn't end up with this issue. Here's the detailed discussion and the pending PR that would solve this issue https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/pull/1994

Comment: This also happens with the JavaScript SDK